# How to find whether the Radio hardware is present in android programatically ...?

Tags: android

I am new to android,is it possible to find whether the  Radio hardware is present in android programatically ?
I have notice that android doesnot have default radio application,so i have to check initially in my application whether Radio hardware is present in the device.
Is any other open source projects in Android Radio.? please help me how to resolve this

Comment: check for the hardware package, if it is available then it is